# jquery ajax is firing error even if i get the response back from the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, response

jquery ajax is firing error even if i get the response back from the server jQuery
[image of success from response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQIXM.png)

[image of error from error function of ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVTrE.png)

Comment: The response body is probably incorrect and cannot be parsed. Make sure it matches the content type the server returns. (for example, you'd get this if you'd have a content type of `application/json` but a body that is empty or not really JSON but HTML for example)

Comment: Here it seems the body is `exists`, so I'm assuming there is a wrong content type (should be `text/plain` in this case)

Comment: Thank you for the immediate help.
the response can be simple string or object, what is the content type i need to provide.

Comment: If it's the simple string use `text/plain`, if it's the object use `application/json`. It has to match what you are sending. But I think it'd be easier to always send an object, like maybe `{"exists": true}` or `{"result": "exists"}` or something.

Comment: i will modify it to object. Thanks for the help!!.